# How can I permanently disable video annotations on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, annotations

Is there a setting or YouTube option, or maybe even a browser plugin, that allows you to disable video annotations for good?

I want to be able to switch them off permanently.

Comment: Just to add, the selected answer below does work but only temporarily. It's possibly a bug with YouTube (which I have reported) but it has been an issue for a while so I don't know when/if it will be fixed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The option is found in the [Account Playback](https://www.youtube.com/account_playback) settings:

1. Click your profile picture and then **YouTube settings**
2. Click **Playback**
3. De-select **Show annotations on videos**
4. Click **Save**

Comment: Here's the link: http://www.youtube.com/account_playback

Comment: Despite having this box unchecked, YouTube still seems to happily show all the annotations by default. I've had them disabled for years, and some YouTube update in the past year seems to have caused it to be ignored.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: You should make it clear that **this is NOT actually permanent.** Annotations ALWAYS get turned back on some time later, no matter how many times you "permanently" turn them off in settings.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I have noticed. Don't the YT settings reset when cookies are cleared as well?

Answer (score 14):

If you're like me and you don't want to help Google collect even more personal information about you by creating an account, you can still disable these annotations using an ad blocking extension that supports [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org)-compatible filters and the following rule :

```
||youtube.com/annotations_
```

Comment: if I could +1 you 1000 times, i would!!

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me now

Comment: This works without needing to log in to YouTube, wonderful!

Comment: For me, the "account playback settings" method worked even on embedded videos on 3rd party websites in Safari, but stopped working on other sites than youtube.com when I switched to Chrome. This took care of that.

Comment: This might be out of date.  Filter lists like "Youtube: Other Annoyances" - https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/yt_annoyances_other.txt - are updated regularly.  See for instance the list of filter lists here: https://github.com/uBlock-LLC/uBlock/wiki/Filter-lists-from-around-the-web