# Is it possible to permanently turn off YouTube annotations?

Tags: youtube, annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I permanently disable video annotations on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/how-can-i-permanently-disable-video-annotations-on-youtube)

I know that on YouTube you can [supposedly turn off annotations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/how-to-disable-video-annotations-on-youtube) by unchecking the box under Settings > Playback. But this option only seems to last a week or so, and then the annotations get turned back on again. Also when logging out and logging in the setting goes back to "Annotations on"

I have unchecked the box and saved so many times and they keep coming back! Is there anyway to disable them permanently?

Comment: "for good" and "permanently" pretty much mean the same thing

Comment: see bounty notice on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/how-can-i-permanently-disable-video-annotations-on-youtube for more info.